# Proper use of AND and OR within IF statements

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2013, forex

Wanting to return a simple YES or NO result in Excel based on data input.  We have had troubles programming this, and just cannot seem to get an answer on how to properly write the IF statement within the cell.

In basic terms, here is our question (not in Excel format but spelled out)...

IF D11="Short" AND G11>0.00 then Yes, otherwise No    OR  IF d11="Long" AND G11<0.00 then Yes, otherwise No.

We cannot seem to get the syntax working properly.  Any suggestions on how to accomplish this task?

UPDATE:  The proper process seems to be to use...
=IF(OR(AND(D11="Short",G11>0),AND(D11="Long",G11<0)), "YES", "NO")

This in fact solves the issue for those fields that are populated.  However, is there a way that to still use this formula, but if d11 is blank to return a blank?

Comment: Perhaps you mean 
IF D11="Short" AND G11>0.00 OR d11="Long" AND G11<0.00 then Yes, otherwise No.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AND`, `OR` and `IF` are all functions not just statements. You have 2 sets of conditions which are valid so put the `AND`s inside the `OR`:

```
=IF(OR(AND(D11 = "Short", G11 > 0), AND(D11 = "Long", G11 < 0)), "YES", "NO")
```

Comment: The above worked very nicely!!  Is there a way that if no data is inputted in d11 for the field to return a blank?

Comment: Huge help, and that worked as well.   Working on helping my daughter with this spreadsheet for school.  I think that we have the "mechanics" working properly but now working on the cosmetics!  Thanks for the time and help.